# Calling javascript function in html link

Tags: php, javascript

im a little stuck. im trying to call a javascript alert when clicking on a link like so

```
 <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="blog-delete.php?blogid=1">Delete</a>
```

which works fine, But im trying to call it inside a php var lik so

```
 $blogtitle . '<p align="right" style="font-size:10px;" ><a onclick="return confirm("Are you sure?")" href="blog-delete.php?blogid=' . $blogid . '">Delete</a> | '. $blogdate . '</p></div> <br />  ';
```

but the double qoute dont allow for the function to work

anyhelp would be great

Many thanks

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: +1 to offset the downvotes. This is a decent question, just because it is trivial to most of us, doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 1):

You are messing up your quotes. When you write this:

```
$v = "This is "some" text";
```

You have double quotes within double quotes, which confuses the parser (as also shown by the syntax highlighter of StackOverflow). To fix, you have to "escape" the ones inside the string:

```
$v = "This is \"some\" text";
```

Or use single quotes:

```
$v = 'This is "some" text';
```

(A lot) more information is found here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php I'd say bookmark that PHP documentation site, it is very good and extensive.

Good luck in learning PHP!

Answer (score 1):

try adding '\'.It will work.
"" signs operarte on a nearest closing tags.thats why it s not working.

Comment: thanks guys sorted new it would be easy but was bangging my head.

Answer (score 0):

escape `"` by `\`
try this

```
 $blogtitle . '<p align="right" style="font-size:10px;" ><a onclick="return confirm(\"Are you sure?\")" href="blog-delete.php?blogid=' . $blogid . '">Delete</a> | '. $blogdate . '</p></div> <br />  ';
```

Answer (score 0):

use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
$blogtitle . '<p align="right" style="font-size:10px;" >
         <a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" href="blog-delete.php?blogid=' . $blogid . '">Delete</a> | '. $blogdate . '</p></div> <br />  
 ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` as an escape character.

More importantly, read up on [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) to see why having calls to Javascript functions in your HTML is now considered deprecated practice.

Comment: thanks will look up on  Unobtrusive Javascript.